# loginActivity is reopened after home key pressed in release mode

Tags: android

My problem is that if i open any activity in the app and then press the home key button .And then reopen the app the login activity is opened instead of opening the current activity the user actually in .

This happens only in release mode .

app manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.TestApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network"
        tools:node="merge">
        <activity android:name=".pages.assitance.question.QuestionAnswerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".pages.tripdetails.TripDetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".pages.profile.EditProfileActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:parentActivityName=".pages.main.MainActivity" android:name=".pages.QrActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".pages.profile.ProfileActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity android:name=".pages.main.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".pages.login.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".core.location.TestService" />

        <service
            android:name=".TestService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and gradle manifest file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
//            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':assi')
    implementation project(':location')
    implementation project(':notification')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //lottie animation
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.0'
    //qr
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    //location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    // Retrofit and OkHttp
    // OkHttp interceptors for logging
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-beta01'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-beta01'
    // use kapt for Kotlin
    //phone number validation
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.2.0'
    //socket.io
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    //library for rating
    implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.4.2'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    //crashlytics
    releaseImplementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
    //firebase push notification
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

if i run the app from android studio in debug or release mode it works normally

it happens only when i generate a release apk

any ideas ?

Comment: Do you handle savedInstanceState correctly in your activity as you can see here? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open the login activity only once and when you will logged in and reopen the app you want to open the home activity then just save the state of the app or save the login status in the shared preferences which you will compare on the splash and than decide that where should you go home activity or login activity.

**Do this when you will get success after calling login function on login activity:**

```
 SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences ("Login",0);
 Editor editor = pref.Editor();
 editor.putBoolean("login",true)
 editor.commit();
```

**Do this in the splash screen code:**

```
Boolean loggedIn = SplashScreen.this.getSharedPreferences("Login",0) .getBoolean 
                   ("login",false);
if(loggedIn) {
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class));
finish();
} else {
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class));
finish();
}
```